# Set a range to a formula then to a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a simpler way of setting a cell in Excel to a formula, then a value.  Below is a subset of a macro I have written.

```
Range("InsuredName").Value = "=INDEX(Data,RetrievalRow,InsuredNameIndex)"
Range("InsuredName").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Can I accomplish this without having to copy, paste-special-values? I have an input sheet in a model where a user puts in necessary inputs and the model performs certain calculations based on those inputs. I have built in functionality where they can save and retrieve their inputs at a later time. So, upon demand to retrieve a specified set of inputs, this macro puts a formula in the appropriate cells on the input tab to perform look-ups in the data tab where the inputs are stored. Then, it pastes that cells to values.  This is done repeatedly for a number of inputs. I assume there is an easier way, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Evaluate()` method

```
Range("InsuredName").Value = Evaluate("INDEX(Data,RetrievalRow,InsuredNameIndex)")
```

If there are no VBA variables to be used, you can also use the shorthand for this which is square brackets:

```
Range("InsuredName").Value = [INDEX(Data,RetrievalRow,InsuredNameIndex)]
```

You can also evaluate a named range to return the range object - so again, you can use shorthand expression:

```
[InsuredName] = [INDEX(Data,RetrievalRow,InsuredNameIndex)]
```

Comment: I like the last option. People really should use Evaluate (and bracketed expressions) more in VBA. It really makes your code more concise and readable.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the guidance! I used the evaluate () method and everything worked!

Answer (score 2):

Replace all with this:

```
With Range("InsuredName")
    .Value = "=INDEX(Data,RetrievalRow,InsuredNameIndex)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!